# Setting row dimension half default column dimension in xymatrix environment

Tags: xymatrix

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \xymatrix{
    \bullet \ar[r]\ar[d] & \bullet\\
    \bullet
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I know that I can adjust row and column dimension with @R or @C. My question is: How can I set the row dimension equal to half the default column dimension? I.e. without affecting the column dimension?

Comment: `@R=4pc @C=2pc`

Comment: @egreg Ahh..maybe I should ask differently: What is the default value? Then I can simply put it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to section 26.3 of the Xy-pic reference manual (`texdoc xyrefer`) the default values for row and column separation are both equal to `2pc`.

You can set the row separation for a single matrix by `@R=<dimen>`, `@R+<dimen>` or `@R-<dimen>`. Similarly, `C` is for the column separation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
  A \ar[r] \ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
  C \ar[r] & D
}
\xymatrix@R=2pc@C=2pc{
  A \ar[r] \ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
  C \ar[r] & D
}
\xymatrix@C=1pc{
  A \ar[r] \ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
  C \ar[r] & D
}

\end{document}
```

[image]